# export.highcharts.com bug? Changing order of series.index values not reflected in exported pics

Tags: highcharts

The exported versions (any type) of this chart do not match the original.  Try it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4RW4/).  Is it a bug?  Specifically, the colors of the series' bars have been reversed.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```

---

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type:"bar"
        },        
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            index:2,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]        
        },{
            index:1,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]        
        }],

        exporting: {
            width: 200
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matches the original (for me) if you put the same width for the chart and for the `exporting` field.

Because the chart adapts the coordinate in function of the size of the final image.

for example :

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```

and

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type:"bar"
        },        
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            index:2,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            color: "#ff0000"        
        },{
            index:1,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            color: "#00ff00"        
        }],

        exporting: {
            width: 400
        }

    });
});
```

Now you have forced the color, the result is the same.

Comment: I tried your code, but the colors of the bars are still reversed.  Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in the question about nature of the problem.

Comment: I edited my post. You can see that I have added a color value in the series. I think it is a bug from the library. So you have to force it.

Comment: That does solve the problem.  I'll submit an issue in their git bug tracker.

Comment: Nevermind, it appears to be fixed in their master branch: http://jsfiddle.net/S4RW4/5/